# Sharepoint 2019 - Open file without download

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

With chrome, when I click on a KeePass document (a file with extension “.kdbx”), the file is downloaded into the download's folder.

Is it possible to open the file like any office document?
I would like that changes to the document made directly to SharePoint without upload the file manually

Answer (score 0):

Only if there is a server-side file handler to do so. SharePoint does not have support for that format out of the box; you'd have to see if a 3rd party provided support.